# Django AutoField increment

Tags: django, django-models

Well I want to auto-increment an model field `conversation-id` which is not a primary key.
Currently, I'm using the following lines of codes, which is very inefficient.

```
web_query_data = WebQuery.objects.all()

        if not web_query_data:
            c_id = 0
        else:
            for data in web_query_data:
                c_id = data.conversation_id


        web_query = WebQuery.objects.create(user_id = request.user.id, sent_to = selected_users, 
                                            user_query = query,date_time = date_time, conversation_id = c_id + 1)
```

It basically gets the last value of field `conversation_id` using a loop and increments it by 1 .

I tried using `models.Autofield` which requires the field to be primary. But according to my needs , I need to insert a data which is sometimes duplicate to the `conversation_id`

Is there any better and efficient method for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the last object and increment from here:

```
query = WebQuery.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
new_query = WebQuery.objects.create(user_id = request.user.id,
                                    sent_to = selected_users,
                                    user_query = query,
                                    date_time = date_time,
                                    conversation_id = query.conversation_id + 1)
```

(assuming that "id" is the primary key of your `WebQuery` model)

I don't know if there is a way to do this automatically in a Django model though.

Comment: Well, there's a bug with this. What if initially I dont have any data in WebQuery, then it will throw an error `list index out of range
`

Comment: __WebQuery.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))__ will return you a dict with your max value