# Field behavior like AutoField + unique_with

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a multi-tenant application with a data model that simplifies to:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Widget(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    sequence_id = ... # question here
```

I want `Widget.sequence_id` to work like an `AutoField` (that is, automatically give me something unique and generally incrementing by 1) but scoped to a single `Widget.owner`. So for instance, when Tenant A creates 3 widgets, they would get `sequence_id`s 1, 2, and 3. Then Tenant B comes along and creates 2 widgets; those widgets get `sequence_id`s 1 and 2. The tenant/user gets no control over the number, but it's something she'll see in the UI. `AutoNumber` is out because from the perspective of a single tenant, they should have sequential widget IDs. GUIDs/UUIDs are out because they need to be human-readable.

I looked through docs on `AutoField` and `unique_together`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072586/django-autofield-increment), which isn't quite what I want. I didn't see anything on djangopackages.com that would solve my problem, though I could have missed it. I asked on the Django users mailing list and got some nibbles, but want broader exposure here on SO.

Is there a common pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I've implemented it like this:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    sequence_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if sequence_id is None:
            # this is a new one, so it needs a new sequence number
            with transaction.atomic():
                last_num = Widget.objects.filter(
                    owner=self.owner).aggregate(
                    Max('sequence_id'))
                self.sequence_id = (last_num['sequence_id__max'] or 0) + 1
                super(Widget, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # just making changes to an existing one
            super(Widget, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```